# Testing to Jessie

Tags: debian

I want to install a fresh debian on my new computer, but I ended up with a problem with the **Z97** chipset, and saw that this problem is resolved in `3.16`, so my question is :

Is it safe to install debian testing and then stay on Jessie when it's out ? Or is there a risk to still have some problem ?

Comment: Very short answer: yes and no, and yes and no

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is reasonably safe to use Debian testing (currently jessie) most of the time. You should be prepared for lots of package churn: new releases of loads of stuff available all the time. You should also expect some minor breakage once in a while and expect some packages to disappear and reappear. But there is also always a risk of important problems that don't get resolved quickly.

What's much safer is to use a backported kernel. wheezy-backports [currently contains kernel version 3.16](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy-backports/linux-image-amd64) so I would very much recommend that you stay with wheezy and use the backported kernel.

Comment: I once used Debian Testing and it ended completely broken. So all I have to do is install linux-image-amd64 how can I choose a specific version?

Comment: If the backported kernel solution is not enough for you due to dependencies or other software needed and you finally install Testing, my advice is this: once you install it and you get it to do what you want, do not update it without a good reason. Testing is usually "good-enough" for most purposes, but it is true that updates lead to breakage.

Comment: Ok, at least I can see if it will solve my problem and then maybe wait for Jessie which might not take that long now, I think